# jupyter installs but 'jupyter' is not recognized when I try to run

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I  installed Jupyter Notebook and it reports requirement satisfied, but when I try to run, it reports 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I am guessing I am missing a path definition, but can't find jupyter.exe.

I see other posts on stackoverflow say to set python library path as per installation instructions, but I search the jupyter installation and found no references to this.

Any suggestions?

btw, complete newbie in Python.

```
c:\Users\john_\Documents>python -m pip install jupyter
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.1 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune>=0.7.4 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.0.0 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from nbformat->notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib!=0.9999,!=0.99999,<0.99999999,>=0.999 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: parso==0.1.0 in c:\users\john_\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
```

Here is the error when I try to run jupyter

```
c:\Users\john_\Documents>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here I show python is installed and can run

```
c:\Users\john_\Documents>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check whether there is an exe named jupyter in the scripts folder inside python installation folder. if yes, then add the scripts folder into the path. 
I would suggest you to use anaconda distribution of python. it will take care of everything.

Comment: no files named jupyter in the script folder. what is anaconda? do I need to remove python that I already installed?

Comment: yes, uninstall python. [click here](https://www.anaconda.com/downloads) you will go to anaconda, choose one of the version and install it.

Comment: issues with anaconda too, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743619/fresh-windows-10-fresh-anaconda-error-404