# fresh windows 10, fresh anaconda, error 404

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On a new PC, new Windows 10 install,
installed 64 bit anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/

from start menu, launch "Jupyter Notebook"
console reports

```
Could not open static file ''
```

and a large number of

```
404 GET /static/.....
```

and the browser displays a blank page.

I'm suspecting the install instructions is missing something.
Any suggestions?

btw, 
  installed for single user ... got the above
  restored windows to a fresh windows, installed anaconda for all users, same issue.

Comment: disabled everything in windows defender, jupyter still does not work

Comment: login with a token ... same error

Comment: installed for single user, all users, no help

Comment: Can you please copy the entire console output into the question? There may be an error early on that you're not showing here, but without that, this question is impossible to answer